# How can build a bar graph in turtle using dictionaries?

Tags: python, graph, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I was just wondering how can I make a bar graph that uses the key-pair from a dictionary to use it for the x-axis and the key-value to draw the graph.

For example: `dic = {'0-10': 24, '10-20': 20, '20-30': 22, '30-40': 27, '40-50': 150, '50-60': 0, '60-70': 231, '70-80': 467, '80-90': 443, '90-100': 86}`

I want the '0-10' as the x-axis and the number as the height of the bar. Here's my my code so bar but I can't find a find to draw the x-axis for it. Also the y-axis will always be 100.

```py
import turtle
from main import value_pairs, key_values

# Basic function to draw "bar graph", it takes the height as prameter
def drawBar(t, height):
    t.begin_fill()
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(height)
    t.write(str(height))
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(40)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(height)
    t.left(90)
    t.end_fill()


xs = value_pairs
maxheight = max(xs)
numbars = len(xs)
border = 5

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.setworldcoordinates(0-border, 0-border, 40*numbars+border, maxheight+border)
wn.bgcolor("white")

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.color("black")
t.fillcolor("white")
t.pensize(3)


for x in value_pairs:
    drawBar(t, x)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've reworked your attempt to roughly do what you describe, filling in missing pieces from your posted code:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

FONT_HEIGHT = 18
FONT = ('Arial', FONT_HEIGHT, 'normal')
BORDER = FONT_HEIGHT

def drawBar(t, datum):
    label, height = datum

    t.left(90)

    t.begin_fill()
    t.forward(height)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(20)
    if height > FONT_HEIGHT:
        t.write(height, align="center", font=FONT)
    t.forward(20)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(height)
    t.end_fill()

    t.left(90)

    t.backward(40)
    t.forward(20)
    t.write(label, align="center", font=FONT)
    t.forward(20)

data = {
    '0-10': 24,
    '10-20': 20,
    '20-30': 22,
    '30-40': 27,
    '40-50': 150,
    '50-60': 0,
    '60-70': 231,
    '70-80': 467,
    '80-90': 443,
    '90-100': 86
}

maxheight = max(data.values())
numbars = len(data)

screen = Screen()
screen.setworldcoordinates(-BORDER, -BORDER, 40 * numbars + BORDER, maxheight + BORDER)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience
turtle.fillcolor('white')
turtle.pensize(3)

for datum in data.items():
    drawBar(turtle, datum)

turtle.hideturtle()
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

**Matplotlib** is the gold standard for data visualization with Python, but it's always fun to try these things with **turtle** to get a better understanding of what's involved in drawing plots.

*Warning:* this approach assumes *ordered dictionaries* -- not a historically safe assumption.

Comment: Great, now put it in a class, and make it such that the bins can be of different widths... ;-) I love it when someone overkills an answer using the wrong tools for the job! +1